# How to add image in my own activity gallery from sd card and capture image

Tags: android, camera, gallery

I have two `button` and one `gallery` in my activity, when I click the button it will redirect to gallery and I would like to select an image. The selected image will be added in my gallery. When I click another button it will capture image from camera and add it in my gallery

how to do that? any idea?

Comment: I hope this will help you.. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304007/take-picture-from-camera-and-choose-from-gallery-and-display-in-image-view

Answer (score 0):

To get image from sd-card follow the link:
[How to pick an image from gallery (SD Card) for my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-a-image-from-gallery-sd-card-for-my-app-in-android)
and for camera follow following tutorial:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-quick-tip-launching-the-camera/