# Android: Drawing Image onto ImageView from a known path on SD Card

Tags: android, imageview, drawable

I have a screen that contains an ImageView which is not visible to user. User would have to browse for a picture from their Gallery, in which I have successfully coded. I've used toast to ensure that the path to the Image selected is correct and have stored the path to a string. My problem is **after selecting the image, how can I draw the selected image on the ImageView by using the path? 
Is it even possible?**

Comment: Hey Matt_K please refer this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304007/take-picture-from-camera-and-choose-from-gallery-and-display-in-image-view) and this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315498/how-to-store-and-retrieve-bitmap-in-sharedpreferences-in-android/7328685#7328685). I hope it will solve your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code to set Bitmap images from a file stored inside a SD-Card.

```
File imgFile = new  File("/sdcard/Images/test_image.jpg");
if(imgFile.exists()){

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);
    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

}
```