# Android camera interrupted

Tags: android, android-activity, camera

In android, is it possible to have the camera interrupted by another activity? What I mean to do is have the application, on start up, run the camera and then when the shutter is clicked, take the user to another activity. So I suppose the camera would close and then another line of code be initiated. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just start the camera intent using the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 0) {
    String result = data.toURI();
    // ...
  }
}
```

Put the code you want to execute after the shutter is clicked in the if statement. If you need more control, use the camera preview functionality. You can find more about that [here](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html).

Comment: This is very good information, thank you. I'll take a look at the docs!

Answer (score 0):

So what's the problem, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304007/take-picture-from-camera-and-choose-from-gallery-and-display-in-image-view) you can see the code of taking picture from camera , you must copy this and change some part of this , in `onActivityResult` function write your code for opening another Activity , and finishing Camera , that's all

Regards Hayk Nahapetyan